# I there a better way to deserialize google homes JSON than this?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dialogflow-es

So I'm trying to deserial Google homes JSON (using Dialogflow) so I can easily work with it, i.e by being able to call it like this:

```
        string myname = tlr?.queryResult?.parameters?.name ?? "Bill";
```

Specifically I'm after a better way to layout the Json to better handle the sub sections, currently with everything at the top level makes a deeply nested Json neigh unreadable.

At the bottom, is what I'd like to have work but I'm not sure how to have C# manage it.

The Json looks like this:

```
{
  "responseId": "64de67a1-7924-437f-aa29-dad7a1451b58",
  "queryResult": 
  {
    "queryText": "Daves Mud",
    "parameters": 
    {
      "name": "Dave"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": 
    [
      {
        "text": 
        {
          "text": 
          [
              ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": 
    {
      "name": "projects/davesmud/agent/intents/4e264eaf-30bc-4db3-8a51-bbfe4b4a3199",
      "displayName": "actions.intent.PLAY_GAME"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "payload": {}
  },
  "session": "projects/davesmud/agent/sessions/a6ef333e-c870-b00e-9b94-ab36d64de757"
}
```

My code to handle it is (which works):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Daves.Mud
{
    public class parameters
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name {get;set;}
    }
    public class queryResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("queryText")]
        public string queryText {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("parameters")]
        public parameters parameters {get; set;}

        [JsonProperty("allRequiredParamsPresent")]
        public string allRequiredParamsPresent {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("fulfillmentMessages")]
        public List<fulfillmentMessages> fulfillmentMessages {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("intent")]
        public intent intent {get; set;}

        [JsonProperty("intentDetectionConfidence")]
        public float intentDetectionConfidence {get; set;}

        [JsonProperty("languageCode")]
        public string languageCode {get; set;}
    }

    public class text
    {
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public List<string> textarr {get; set;}
    }

    public class fulfillmentMessages
    {
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public text text {get; set;}
    }
    public class intent
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name {get; set;}

        [JsonProperty("displayName")]
        public string displayName {get; set;}
    }

    public class payload
    {
        // don't know what gets passed to this yet.
    }

    public class originalDetectIntentRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("payload")]
        public payload payload {get; set;}
    }

    public class  TopLevelRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("responseID")]
        public string responseID {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("queryResult")]
        public queryResult queryResult {get; set;}

        [JsonProperty("originalDetectIntentRequest")]
        public originalDetectIntentRequest originalDetectIntentRequest {get; set;}

        [JsonProperty("session")]
        public string session {get; set;}

    }


    public static class HttpTriggerAlexaAdventure
    {
        [FunctionName("HttpTriggerAlexaAdventure")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            TopLevelRequest tlr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TopLevelRequest>(requestBody);

            string myname = tlr?.queryResult?.parameters?.name ?? "Bill";


/*            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
*/
            return(ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {myname}");
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to have is something like this, note this will not compile because the classes can't be used in this fashion with properties (I think they're called).

```
public class  TopLevelRequest
{
   [JsonProperty("responseID")]
    public string responseID {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("queryResult")]
    public class queryResult 
    {
        [JsonProperty("queryText")]
        public string queryText {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("parameters")]
        public class parameters 
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string name {get;set;}
        }

        [JsonProperty("allRequiredParamsPresent")]
        public string allRequiredParamsPresent {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("fulfillmentMessages")]
        public class fulfillmentMessages
        {
          [JsonProperty("text")]
          public class text
          {
              [JsonProperty("text")]
              public List<string> textarr {get; set;}
          }



...
```

As above the class is defined within the other class so there is only one top level class defined, and the json is much easier to follow, because you don't need to jump all around the source code.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated because if that is the best c# can do for readability for json processing I'll be longing for how I used to do it in Perl.... :-)

EDIT - I've played some more, and found a way to at least keep the hierarchy which is primarily what I was after.  To say it's pretty though would be a bald face lie, but I believe it to be improved.

```
public class  TopLevelRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("responseID")] public string responseID {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("queryResult")] public queryResult_class queryResult {get; set;}  public class queryResult_class
    {
        [JsonProperty("queryText")] public string queryText {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("parameters")] public parameters_cl parameters {get; set;}  public class parameters_cl
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")] public string name {get;set;}
        }

        [JsonProperty("allRequiredParamsPresent")] public string allRequiredParamsPresent {get;set;}

        [JsonProperty("fulfillmentMessages")] public List<fulfillmentMessages_class> fulfillmentMessages {get;set;}  public class fulfillmentMessages_class
        {
            [JsonProperty("text")] public text_class text {get; set;}  public class text_class
            {
                [JsonProperty("text")] public List<string> textarr {get; set;}
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("intent")] public intent_class intent {get; set;}  public class intent_class
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")] public string name {get; set;}
            [JsonProperty("displayName")] public string displayName {get; set;}
        }

        [JsonProperty("intentDetectionConfidence")] public float intentDetectionConfidence {get; set;}
        [JsonProperty("languageCode")] public string languageCode {get; set;}
    }

    [JsonProperty("originalDetectIntentRequest")] public originalDetectIntentRequest_class originalDetectIntentRequest {get; set;}  public class originalDetectIntentRequest_class
    {
        [JsonProperty("payload")] public payload_class payload {get; set;} public class payload_class
        {
            // don't know what gets passed to this yet.
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("session")] public string session {get; set;}
}
```

If there's a better way please let me know :-) !

EDIT 2 - 
I tried doing what the one poster suggested which was to copy the json, and paste it into visual studio using, edit, paste special, Paste json as classes.

It worked straight out of the box, this is what it produces, I'm sure I could reorder it as I did above, I was surprised I didn't need any of the JsonProperties which simplifies the code alot on its own.

This is the code that it produces:

```
public class TopLevelRequest
{
    public string responseId { get; set; }
    public Queryresult queryResult { get; set; }
    public Originaldetectintentrequest originalDetectIntentRequest { get; set; }
    public string session { get; set; }
}

public class Queryresult
{
    public string queryText { get; set; }
    public Parameters parameters { get; set; }
    public bool allRequiredParamsPresent { get; set; }
    public Fulfillmentmessage[] fulfillmentMessages { get; set; }
    public Intent intent { get; set; }
    public int intentDetectionConfidence { get; set; }
    public string languageCode { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Intent
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}

public class Fulfillmentmessage
{
    public Text text { get; set; }
}

public class Text
{
    public string[] text { get; set; }
}

public class Originaldetectintentrequest
{
    public Payload payload { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
}
```

This is awesome as I think it took me 2-3 hrs to work out the original code to map it, and this was nearly instant! :)  Also his recommended site is promising.

Comment: no matter how good you structure this question stack overflow will never respond to a question like this in a descent matter. they will say that it is to vague or opinion based question

Comment: That's perhaps true, but I wasn't sure of a better place to ask it, and I believe I do have a valid issue, where my original working source I would call largely unreadable/unmaintainable over a larger project/json file.  Thank-you for noticing the formatting, I spend time to try and make it readable, I forgot to mention the code in the first post is functional.  Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CodeReview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for this since this is primarily opinion-based in regards to making the code more usable, which is a noble cause.

One thing I'll add is that a great way to make sense of a large Json in Visual Studio is to create a new .cs file and have the Json in your clipboard: Edit > Paste Special > Paste Json as Classes. Pretty handy in regards to a jumping off point.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure it'll let me post code here but for those curious, this is what doing that outputs for this,